# Cannot insert song into playlist

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, playlist, mediastore, android-music-player

I'm trying to add songs to existing playlist but for some reason the song is not being added. No errors are encountered though. I'm checking the URI in log, it always gives null. I'm passing both the playlist id and song object. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
 public static void AddSongToPlaylist(SongInfoModel songInfoModel, long pID, Context context )
{


    Uri pUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", pID);

    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID, songInfoModel.getSongID());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE, songInfoModel.getSongName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ARTIST, songInfoModel.getArtistName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DURATION, songInfoModel.getDuration());
    resolver.insert(pUri,values);
    resolver.notifyChange(Uri.parse("content://media"), null);
    Log.i("URI:",resolver.insert(pUri, values)+"");


}
```

Passing pID and song object :

```
 Playlistadapter = new ListPlayListAdapter(finalDialogPlaylist, getContext(), new ListPlayListAdapter.ItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClickListener(PlaylistsModel playlistsModel, int position) {

                          Playlists.AddSongToPlaylist(song,playlistsModel.getPlaylistID(),getContext());

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161928/discussion-on-question-by-rektirino-cannot-insert-song-into-playlist).

Comment: Can you guys please use chat instead, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161928/discussion-on-question-by-rektirino-cannot-insert-song-into-playlist. Comments are not for extended discussions. Prolonged discussions would eventually lead to locking the posts from further interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong arguments.

All that is required is as follows:

```
         Uri newuri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri(
            "external", playlist_id);

        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER, pos);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID, audio_id);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAYLIST_ID,
                playlist_id);
```